# Weld class not found when executing cdi-unit test

Tags: cdi, weld, jboss-weld, cdi-unit

I have a JEE project that is deployed on wildfly 10 smoothly.

I'm trying to write junit tests for my CDI beans with cdi-unit library (http://bryncooke.github.io/cdi-unit/)

My `pom.xml` looks like the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
     <groupId>org.jglue.cdi-unit</groupId>
     <artifactId>cdi-unit</artifactId>
     <version>4.0.1</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

However my sample test:

```
@RunWith(CdiRunner.class)
public class SampleTest {

   @Inject
   private Foo foo;

   @Test
   public void testFoo(){
      foo.bar();
   }
}
```

fails to initialize due to missing weld class:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/weld/environment/se/Weld
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 17 more
```

CDI-UNIT manual says [here](http://bryncooke.github.io/cdi-unit/#using-a-specific-version-of-weld) that it automatically uses it's own version of Weld, hence there is no need to explicitly add any weld libraries in pom.xml.

Any help please?

Comment: Check the 'dependency tree' with maven to see it actually IS added

Comment: already checked. cdi-unit does not fetch any weld libraries

Comment: If I may suggest an alternative approach, **try [weld-junit](https://github.com/weld/weld-junit) instead**. It supports both, JUnit4 and JUnit5 and it designed for unit-testing your CDI beans. It basically bootstraps Weld SE container in customizable way in order to let you use real beans in those tests, but it allows for simple mocking too if that's what you need.

Comment: @geo Sorry, that bit of the manual is no longer true as of CDI-Unit 4. That section has now been removed, and the quickstart updated, because you now have to specify your own version of Weld SE. (The reason was to do with supporting Weld 1, 2 or 3 in the same code base.)

Answer (score 2):

You should include weld-se into your maven dependencies.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-se-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

add
     
as is fitting the version your wildfly-weld uses.

If you want more than the Simulation of the CDI-Container but also some have a realistic simulation of EJB-Functionality  like persistence, transactionality, 
message driven beans, try [ejb-cdi-unit](https://github.com/1and1/ejb-cdi-unit/)
It is derived from cdi-unit.
There you can also find some example-projects which might help with your cdi-unit-issues.